# Form in C# asp.net core send a list

Tags: c#, forms, list, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to pass a list of n subtance to my controller but the list does not pass when I have this form

```cs
<form asp-controller="AdminAirbus" asp-action="AjoutDeclaration" method="post">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListSubtances.Count(); i++) { <input asp-for="ListSubtances[i].CasNumber" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="ListSubtances[i].Commentaire" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="ListSubtances[i].EcNumber" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="ListSubtances[i].Quantite" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="ListSubtances[i].Reach_DeclarationId" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="ListSubtances[i].TypeArticle" type="hidden" />
    }
    <label> Recherche d'une personne </label>
    <input asp-for="ListSubtances" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="reach_Declaration.ArticleId"></label>
        <input asp-for="reach_Declaration.ArticleId" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="reach_Declaration.ArticleId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="reach_Declaration.DateDeclaration"></label>
        <input asp-for="reach_Declaration.DateDeclaration" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="reach_Declaration.DateDeclaration" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="reach_Declaration.EntrepriseId"></label>
        <input asp-for="reach_Declaration.EntrepriseId" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="reach_Declaration.EntrepriseId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Valider la déclaration</button>
</form>
```

But when i have just this in the form that pass

```cs
<form asp-controller="AdminAirbus" asp-action="AjoutDeclaration" method="post">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListSubtances.Count(); i++)
    {
    <input asp-for="ListSubtances[i].CasNumber" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="ListSubtances[i].Commentaire" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="ListSubtances[i].EcNumber" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="ListSubtances[i].Quantite" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="ListSubtances[i].Reach_DeclarationId" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="ListSubtances[i].TypeArticle" type="hidden" /> 
    }
    <button type="submit">Valider la déclaration</button>
</form>
```

My action in the controler is 
take in  enter AjoutDeclarationViewModel viewModel
and the class is :

```cs
public class AjoutDeclarationViewModel
{
  public Substance substance { get; set; }
  public Reach_Declaration reach_Declaration { get; set; }
  public List<Substance> ListSubtances { get; set; }
  public int Nombre_Subtance { get; set; }
}
```

How can I fix my form for send the list of `subtance` and the `reach_declaration`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the below line in your first code snippet

```
<input asp-for="ListSubtances" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
```

You could check the Form-Data in the DevTools , the above code passes `ListSubtances: System.Collections.Generic.List'1[TestExample.Models.Declarations.Substance]` to overrides the `ListSubtances` in the loop,so you get the ListSubtances is null .